# Python: how to have character "\n" without have another row in file

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

I was able to print in a file with python.
I have a dictionary with this form:

```
dict['name']=x
dict['list']="\n".join(mylist)
```

When I print on file I don't have a single row but I have the same number as number of "\n".

How can I have a file of this form:

```
name1 item1
      item2
      item3
name2 item1
      item2
name3 item1
      item2
```

...

Thanks for answers

Edit with that code I have this:

```
name1 item1
item2
item3
name2 item1
item2
name3 item1
item2
```

Intead I want the same that I have when in excel I press ALT + ENTER

Edit2:

If I have a CSV file I want this:

```
CELL A:1 with name1
CELL B:1 with item1\nitem2\nitem3
CELL A:2 with name2
CELL B:2 with item\nitem2
...
```

Comment: Can you show us your write statement to the file?

Comment: dict['list']=" ".join(mylist). Or do you need the /n as your question title suggests?

Comment: that is a nice edit to show what you want. When you add what @sudobangbang asks for, please also add what it does now.

Comment: @JeremyKahan I don't want the list separated by space. I want the same in excel when I press ALT+ENTER. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a dictionary mapping strings to lists.

```
d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [1,2,3]}

for k in d:
    name = k
    for item in d[k]:
        print('{:<5} {:<5}'.format(name, item))
        name = ''
```

Output:

```
a     1
      2
      3
b     1
      2
      3
```

To print to a file with this, we'll open the file and then print to it using [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for k in d:
        name = k
        for item in d[k]:
            print('{:<5} {:<5}'.format(name, item), file=f)
            name = ''
```

The `'{:<5} {:<5}'` is a basic use of the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec).  All it's really saying is "I want the two arguments to `format` to be formatted to width five, left aligned and separated by a space".  I suggest you look around online for examples of `format`, it can be very powerful when you know how to use it.

EDIT:  Oh, I didn't see that you were working with a `csv` file.  You need to use quote characters so the file knows that the newlines are not the start of new rows

```
import csv

d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [1,2,3]}

with open('filename.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, quotechar='"')
    for k in d:
        name = k
        item = '\n'.join(i for i in d[k])
        w.writerow([str(k), item])
```

Comment: Now I will try. Can you explain me?

Comment: @all_key_the I'd be happy to explain.  Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand the part of  {:<5} {:<5}. Unfortunely I started with python 3 weeks ago

Comment: What version of python are you on?  if you're using python 3, you can print to a file from the `print` function

Comment: @all_key_the I've edited a more verbose explanation into the body of my answer

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that in CSV file it isn't as I want. I want CELL A:1 with "b" and CELL B:1 with(1 2 3 in vertical (like if I press ALT + ENTER). The CELL A:2 with "a" and CELL B:2 with the same

Comment: I think your original solution actually works, it's just that Excel is bad about displaying csv files properly.  If you select cell B1, it has all the values, but is just displaying the first line